# c++ evaluation of ambigous sum expression

Tags: c++

Take the following example:

```
int g_X;
int func() {
 return ++g_X;  // using g_X++ is not an option
}
int main() {
 g_X = 0;
 int a = g_X + func();
 g_X = 0;
 int b = func() + g_X;
 g_X = 0; int temp = g_X;
 int c = temp + func();

 return 0;
}
```

a and b are both 2, c has the expected value 1 (tested with Visual Studio 2010 to 2015). I read that sums are not associated with a sequence point (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) and therefore the order is not fixed. Yet I thought that the value of g_X gets captured before the function call.
Am I really in undefined behavior territory or is there some way not having to use the temp var?

Comment: The order of evaluations of operands is unspecified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically
>   sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with
>   respect to the execution of the called function.

([intro.execution]/15)

Therefore, in an expression of the form `g_X + func()` or `func() + g_X`, it's true that the `+` operator doesn't introduce any sequencing constraint, but nevertheless the access to `g_X` within `main` either happens before or after the body of `func()`, you just can't predict which. This implies that the behaviour is defined, but whether `a` is 1 or 2 is unpredictable. Likewise, whether `b` is 1 or 2 is unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

At first sight this looks like an undefined behavior because, quoting §1.9/15:

> If a side effect on a scalar
>   object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
>   using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

and your example seemingly satisfies these conditions:

1. Evaluation of operands of + operator are unsequenced relative to each other (but see below).
2. There is a side effect on a scalar object (`func` increments `g_X`).
3. There is a computation using the value of the same scalar object (`g_X`).

On the other hand, as pointed out in the Brian's answer, function call does introduce sequencing, although indeterminate. According to this argument this is not an undefined behavior, but merely unspecified.